# React get class name of parent <li> when clicking link from child <span>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a tree menu component which is outputting the following format:

```
<li class="rct-node rct-node-parent rct-node-collapsed">
<span class="rct-title">192.168.1.61</span></span></span></li>
```

I need to get the class of the li when the "rct-title" value is clicked so that I can run a conditional statement if the class is "rct-node". I'm a JS newbie and am wondering if there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: I am not sure why you need that? You are passing class statically right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that `class` is not valid syntax for React (jsx) it should be `className`

Having said that, you can use `e.target.parentElement.className`

Like so:

```
class App extends Component {
  handleGetClassName = e => {
    console.log(e.target.parentElement.className);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <li
          className="rct-node rct-node-parent rct-node-collapsed"
          onClick={this.handleGetClassName}
        >
          <span className="rct-title">192.168.1.61</span>
        </li>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

It will console.log a string `rct-node rct-node-parent rct-node-collapsed`

UPDATE:

If you only need the first className you can do this:

```
  handleGetClassName = e => {
    const className = e.target.parentElement.className.split(' ')[0];
    console.log(className);
  };
```

Now it will give you only `rct-node`